# VBS Taking extremely long time to delete

Tags: vbscript, scripting

We have a vbs script that runs during our overnight process that deletes the old backups, then creates the new ones for the night. In a few of our locations, we're having issues with the delete section taking an extremely long time to delete.

I work in the IT department for a restaurant and this code was written by our software provider, who is absolutely no help. This is taking way too long and causing the stores to not open on time.

Here is the code used:

```
   If FSO_FileExists(sDest & "\" & sZip) Then
      FSO_DeleteFile(sDest & "\" & sZip)
   End If

Function FSO_DeleteFile(sFile)
   Dim oErr: oErr = Err: Err.Clear
   If Not bDebugScript Then On Error Resume Next
   Dim fsName: fsName = "FSO_DeleteFile"
   Dim oFSO: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   oFSO.DeleteFile sFile, True
   FSO_DeleteFile = (Err.Number = 0)
   If IsObject(oLog) Then oLog.WriteLog fsName & ": " & sFile
   If Err.Number <> 0 And IsObject(oLog) Then oLog.WriteLog "ERROR: " & fsName & ": (" &    Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
   Err = oErr
End Function

Function FSO_FileExists(sFile)
   Dim oErr: oErr = Err: Err.Clear
   If Not bDebugScript Then On Error Resume Next
   Dim fsName: fsName = "FSO_FileExists"
   Dim oFSO: Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Dim bExists
   bExists = oFSO.FileExists(sFile)
   FSO_FileExists = bExists
   If IsObject(oLog) Then oLog.WriteLog fsName & ": (" & CStr(bExists) & ") " & sFile
   If Err.Number <> 0 And IsObject(oLog) Then oLog.WriteLog "ERROR: " & fsName & ": (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description
   Err = oErr
End Function
```

The logs show:

02/26/2014 04:22:17.825 FSO_FileExists: (True) D:\backup\Logs.zip

02/26/2014 04:22:17.886 FSO_DeleteFile: D:\backup\Logs.zip

02/26/2014 04:56:20.544 WSHShell_Run: '"C:\Zip.exe" -D "D:\backup\Logs.zip" *' Result(0)

Obviously, 34 minutes is a long time to delete a file. I hope I have provided enough information. If I need anything else let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If the same script behaves badly on some computers, you should check the pecularities of those machines.
2. As you write to the log before (04:22:17.825 FSO_FileExists) and **after** (04:22:17.886 FSO_DeleteFile) the deletion, the delete is not to blame.
3. If you log **after** the ZIP process (04:56:20.544 WSHShell_Run: '"C:\Zip.exe"), then the 34 mins were spent to prepare and do the zip; I'd concentrate further research there

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing that convolute with this:

```
filename = oFSO.BuildPath(sDest, sZip)
If oFSO.FileExists(filename) Then
  oLog.Write "Deleteing file " & filename
  On Error Resume Next
  oFSO.DeleteFile filename
  If Err Then oLog.Write "ERROR: " & filename & ": (" & Err.Number & ") " _
    & Err.Description
  On Error Goto 0
Else
  oLog.Write "File " & filename & " not found"
End If
```

The script should know if it instantiated a logger or not, so it's pointless to check each time you write a log line.